# Ruby on rails & Passenger & paperclip | Image uploaded but 404 on passenger mod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, passenger

Everything works on the Ror's own server (Webrick), but when I tried out on Apache(+Passenger mod) I got always 404 (not found) error.

You can check this here: http://keidan.hopto.org/rails/phoenix/public/guild.

I think the main problem is that I can't access the app's public folder...

My vhost file:

```
ServerName keidan.hopto.org
ServerAlias keidan.hopto.org

DocumentRoot /var/www/
RackBaseURI /rails/phoenix/public

<Directory /var/www/rails/phoenix/public >
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

...

Comment: If you put a static html file in the public folder, can you access it?

Comment: Not really. There are some html files by default (404, 422, 500...). I can't access these pages...

Comment: You should probably ask on the superuser site.